# Android Studio's layout editor failing to apply android:windowActionBarOverlay property

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, graphical-layout-editor

I am developing a simple app in Android Studio, and I am testing it on a real device (Asus zenfone 5 & Android 4.4.2). In the main activity I have applied this layout:

```
<LinearLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
 tools:context="madapps.mysecondapp.MainActivity"  

 android:id="@+id/activity_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"     
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize" 
 android:orientation="horizontal" 
 android:background="@drawable/background_deathstar">

  <EditText 
      android:id="@+id/edit_message" 
      android:text="@string/message" android:layout_weight="1"     
      android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:hint="@string/edit_message" android:textColor="#FFF" />

  <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:text="@string/button_send" 
      android:onClick="sendMessage" />
</LinearLayout>
```

with this style.xml applied to the activity

```
<resources>
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

What I want to do is testing a background image on different screen sizes and densities (dpi).
Now, the problem is that while in my physical device the property

```
    android:windowActionBarOverlay
```

is applied properly, laying out my action bar on top of my background image, this is not working equally within Android Studio's layout editor, meaning that my image begins at the end of the action bar.

ps. I have also noticed that apart from ignoring the windowActionBarOverlay property, my action bar fails to load my custom action buttons. I think these two problems are somewhat related.

Any suggestions?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I should have not expected Android Studio's layout editor to reflect what I'm seeing on devices, because it's only using a subset of the real Android layout system.﻿ 
Actually my action bar is hidden and shown programmatically, and the layout editor is only supposed to serve as a way to drag-and-drop widgets and preview a layout while editing the XML.